# The correct way to tune the C parameter of SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm, cross-validation, training-data

I have a dataset which has three splits (training-validation-testing). What is the best way to tune the C parameter? Do i train on the training and evaluate on the validation partition? Is it correct to perform k-fold validation when you have an already partiotioned data?

Any explanation will be truly appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: Usually you tune your parameter C on cross-validation step. C defines the weight of how much samples inside the margin contribute to the overall error. Consequently, with C you can adjust how hard or soft your large margin classification should be. With a low C, samples inside the margins are penalized less than with a higher C. With a C of 0, samples inside the margins are not penalized anymore - which is the one possible extreme of disabling the large margin classification. With an infinite C you have the other possible extreme of hard margins.

Comment: @DanielChepenko thank you. But is cross-validation performed on the training or validation split? I think it's validation, but I've seen alot perform it on training splits.

Answer (score 0):

I generally dont split my data into 3 parts. I use 20% of my train data randomly for validation in 5-10 iterations and check accuracy with different C.

Suppose I take 5 iterations and 4 different C to check:

```
**Iteration**           **C**        **Accuracy**
1                        10            92
1                        1             91.23
1                        0.1           90.9
1                        0.01          89.88
```

Similarly I do this for 5 more iterations (each iteration provides a new validation set randomly from train data) and the C value with the highest mean accuracy along different iterations is chosen as the best parameter.

Alternatively, You can use GridSearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV to achieve the same.

Comment: How about if I have a benchmark dataset that has training, development and testing split, can i use the development split alone to tune the parameters? I've see practitioners in the literature say 'we tuned the parameters using the development split' but I dont know what they exactly mean by it. Thanks